# Can I use JNDI to share a MongoClient instance?

Tags: java, mongodb, jetty, jndi, mongo-java

I'm using Jetty for a web server. I have built a custom LoginService/realm that uses MongoDb to get users. This LoginService is in it's own jar and is on the jetty server container's classpath.

I also want to use MongoDb in my web application. Normally, for SQL, you would set up a connection pool shared via JNDI. Can I do something similar with MongoDb?

Each MongoClient manages a connection pool. Can I store arbitrary objects in JNDI (ie. a `MongoClient` instance) or do I have to use the `ObjectFactory` interface?

If I have to create some kind of ObjectFactory, can I basically turn it into a singleton and return the same instance of MongoClient?

I don't fully understand JNDI because there are few resources out there that really explain the magic of it, so I may not even be asking the right questions.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this in your server.xml:

```
<mongo id="mongo">
    <hostNames>YOUR.MONGODB.HOSTNAME.HERE</hostNames>
</mongo>

<mongoDB databaseName="YOUR_DATABASE_NAME" jndiName="mongo/mongodb" mongoRef="mongo"/>
```

Then in your java class:

```
@Resource(name = "mongo/mongodb")
DB mongoDB;

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  DBCollection table = mongoDB.getCollection("YOUR_TABLE_NAME");
  // etc.
}
```